# How to create event handler in Visual Studio C# for editclear() method when developind addin for MS Project 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, add-in, ms-project

I am developing an addin for MS Project 2010 in Visual Studio 2010 C#. The event ProjectBeforeTaskChange does not occur when I clear the content of a task field in MS Project by using "Delete" button. When the "Delete" button is pressed the editclear method is called and there is no event for this action in Visual Studio. I thought that probably I can make an event handler when editclear is called. Do you know how can I do this ? or is there any other solution ?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In order to solve this issue, I have implemented the SelectionChange event in which I am checking if the value of a field has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this issue, I have implemented the SelectionChange event in which I am checking if the value of a field has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I use `event _EProjectDoc_ChangeEventHandler Change` because I haven't found `SelectionChange`. Maybe because I use MS Project 2013 AddIn. But thing is that there is no useful data going with the event (only passing `Project`  object). I only got `ActiveCell` which is not always the one that was changed, e.g. when pressing enter active cell is one below.

edit: I've found property `applcation.MoveAfterReturn` which set to false, remains current selection active after pressing enter:-)